# SQL INNER JOIN and AVG() returning wrong data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to select all rows from a table containing data about a video and then afterwards i am joining all of their ratings as an `AVG()` from another table.

The thing is there is only 1 row for each video but many ratings for each video, so i have to get all the ratings and find the average for each video.

I have this piece of SQL

```
SELECT t1.video_id,  
t1.video_title,  
t1.video_url,  
t1.video_views,  
AVG(t2.videos_rating_rating) AS rating 
FROM videos_approved t1 
INNER JOIN videos_rating t2 
ON t1.video_id = t2.videos_rating_video_fk 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY video_id 
DESC LIMIT 12
```

The SQL returns a result but it only returns 1 row with a wrong Average value?

Can someone explain to me why this is going on and what i could do instead?

Comment: What is the purpose of `where 1`?  Also, where is your `group by` clause?

Comment: You should add a `group by` clause. In most dbms's it's a syntax error to omit it.

Comment: The where 1 to select all rows @DanBracuk :)

Comment: Where 1 to select all rows?  Take it out and see if there is any difference in the results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` here.  In your current query you are taking an average over the entire table.

```
SELECT
    t1.video_id,  
    t1.video_title,  
    t1.video_url,  
    t1.video_views,  
    AVG(t2.videos_rating_rating) AS rating 
FROM videos_approved t1 
INNER JOIN videos_rating t2 
    ON t1.video_id = t2.videos_rating_video_fk 
GROUP BY
    t1.video_id
ORDER BY
    t1.video_id DESC
LIMIT 12
```

Note that my answer assumes that `video_id` is the primary key of the `videos_approved` table, in which case we may select any column from that table even when grouping by the `video_id`.  If not, then strictly speaking we would have to do another join.

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for, thanks alot Tim :)

Comment: Dont worry @tim stack overflow dont allow me to accept an answer right away :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`. 
See more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17031621) and on [this page](https://academy.vertabelo.com/blog/introduction-using-aggregate-functions-joins/) (search for `AVG` + `GROUP BY` + `JOINS`)